# Converter Perl script fix

Tags: mysql, regex, sqlite, perl

I am trying to use a small Perl script in order to convert SQL INSERT statements from MySQL syntax into SQLite syntax. But the script has a bug and can't convert the string constants properly in some corner cases.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>){
    s/\\'/''/g;                # Use '' instead of \'
    s/\\"/"/g;                 # Use " instead of \"
    s/\\r\\n/\r\n/g;           # Convert escaped \r\n to literal
    s/\\\\/\\/g;               # Convert escaped \ to literal
    s/ auto_increment//g;      # Remove auto_increment
    s/^[UN]*?LOCK TABLES.*//g; # Remove locking statements
    print;
}
```

The problem is that in the case of the following MySQL string:

```
'It doesn\'t work :-\\'
```

It generates wrong SQLite string:

```
'It doesn''t work :-\''
```

instead of the proper:

```
'It doesn''t work :-\'
```

What is wrong in the script?

EDIT:

And how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're processing `\'` before `\\`. You need to handle backslashes in the order they are encountered, so you need to do everything in one pass.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %escapes = (
   n => "\n",
   r => "\r",
);

while (<>) {
    s{\\([\Wrn])}{ $escapes{$1} // ( $1 eq "'" ? "''" : $1 ) }eg;
    s/ auto_increment//g;
    next if /^(?:UN)?LOCK TABLES/;
    print;
}
```

Note the proper way of optionally matching `UN`.

Comment: There is some mistake: `echo "'This doesn\'t work :-\\'" | ./mysql2sqlite.pl` outputs `'This doesn''t work :-''`

Comment: @johnfound, What's the output of `echo "'This doesn\'t work :-\\'"`

Comment: Yes, it is my fault. :)

Answer (score 0):

The first substitution `s/\\'/''/g;` replace the last `\'` by `''`, so

```
'It doesn\'t work :-\\'
#                    ^^
```

becomes

```
'It doesn\'t work :-\''
```

I guess you want to replace `\'` only when it is not followed by a non-word character `\W`.

*I'm using here only the 2 relevant substitutions for this case*

```
my $str = <<'EOD';
insert into tbl values ('it doesn\'t work :-\\', 42, 33, 'and this doesn\'t work as well :-\\', 1024);
EOD
say "before: ",$str;
$str =~ s/\\'(?!\W)/''/g;
$str =~ s/\\\\/\\/g;
say "after: ",$str;
```

**Output:**

```
before: insert into tbl values ('it doesn\'t work :-\\', 42, 33, 'and this doesn\'t work as well :-\\', 1024);

after: insert into tbl values ('it doesn''t work :-\', 42, 33, 'and this doesn''t work as well :-\', 1024);
```

Comment: Hm, it is not actually the end of the string, because it is only a part of MySQL line. For example: `insert into tbl values ('it dosn\'t work :-\\', 42, 33, 'and this doesn\'t work as well :-\\', 1024);`

Comment: @johnfound: I've changed the negative lookahead. If you have other cases, please, [edit you question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53895067/edit) and add more test cases.

Comment: @Toto, That tails for `'\\\'!'`. It should gives `'\''!'`, but it gives `'\\'!'`

Comment: I meant  "That fails"